# jQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'geocomplete'

Tags: jquery, geolocation

I am getting exception as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'geocomplete'
```

whenever i try to include `instantclick.js` on to the page. The page has one autocomplete box to search places as below:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Start Typing Your Location" id="geocomplete" 
 autocomplete="off" class="chkmeloc" onblur="validatefoem()"/>
```

`instantclick.js` and `geocomplete.js` is included as below:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $dir; ?>js/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script> 
<script>

      $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          map: ".map_canvas",
          details: "form",
          types: ["geocode", "establishment"]
        });

        $("#find").click(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });
      });
</script>
<script src="js/instantclick.min.js" data-no-instant></script>
<script data-no-instant>InstantClick.init();</script>
<style>
    #instantclick-bar {
      background: #ed3e49;
      color: #ed3e49;
    }
</style>
```

I also tried adding `data-no-instant` tag to scripts but in vain.Please help me to identify the issue.

When i refresh the page again after one load then it works fine.. looks like It is not getting loaded first time

Comment: Your PHP variable $var has right value? Seems like geocomplete.js was not loaded.

Comment: @JensonMJohn ,... ya that is right but when i remove `instantclick.js` then `geocomplete.js` is loaded perfectly. So how both are conflicting that i am not geting

Comment: From where you're getting $dir? Are you sure $dir has correct value? I'm not talking anything related with instantclick.js

Comment: @JensonMJohn .. $dir has correct value.. It picks Server path i.e. http://example.com/js/filename.js ....

Comment: If you add `data-no-instant` to the `<script>` tag that contains the declaration of geocomplete (i.e. `$("#geocomplete").geocomplete({...` etc. does that work?

Comment: i tried adding that also... after adding on that the error didn't pop up but geo complete also do not work

Comment: As well as that did you try moving the `instantclick.min.js` script tag just below the `geocomplete` script tag and swapping `$(function(){` for `InstantClick.on('change', function() {`.

Comment: @mccannf .. i tried it now as <script src="js/jquery.geocomplete.js"></script><script src="js/instantclick.min.js" data-no-instant></script><script>InstantClick.on('change', function() { .... but same error there

Comment: @mccannf .. anymore inputs please

Comment: Sorry - no other ideas. Just guessing now :) If you change `<script>InstantClick.on('change', function() {` to `<script data-no-instant>InstantClick.on('change', function() {` does that help?

Comment: @mccannf .. did that too..... but if i adopt earlier approach and i refresh page then geocomplete gets loaded. :( .. weird